# 400 Bad request on Java Webclient multipart/formdata post request

Tags: java, api, rest, post

Im having problems on posting a multipart/formdata request to a REST api. The request returns an 400 Bad Request response.

This is how the request should look like. The link shows you a screenshot captured on a successful request by the web interface.
[Successful request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGzaJ.jpg)

This is the Java code I created.

```
public void importModel(String projectId, String modelId, MultipartFile file, String fileName) throws IOException {
    MultipartBodyBuilder builder = new MultipartBodyBuilder();
    builder.part("data", file.getBytes(), MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
        .header("Content-Disposition", "form-data; name=data; filename=" + fileName);
    MultiValueMap<String, HttpEntity<?>> parts = builder.build();

    WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder()
        .filters(exchangeFilterFunctions -> {
          exchangeFilterFunctions.add(logRequest());
          exchangeFilterFunctions.add(logResponse());
        })
        .build();

    String request = webClient.post()
        .uri(getBaseUriBuilder()
            .pathSegment(getTeamSlug())
            .path(API_PATH_PROJECTS)
            .pathSegment(projectId)
            .path(API_PATH_MODEL)
            .pathSegment(modelId)
            .path("/importasync")
            .build())
        .contentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
        .contentLength(file.getSize())
        .header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, getPrefixedAuthToken())
        .body(BodyInserters.fromMultipartData(parts))
        .exchange()
        .flatMap(FlatService::apply)
        .block();

    return;
  }
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thank in advance!

Comment: sorry, can't see images on other sites

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to send the request with alternative Software like POSTMAN.
There you can check for the request properties that are being sent with the request
a 400 error can occur due to the following issues with your request

1. **Wrong URL**: Same as 404-Error a Bad Request is generated, when the user types in a wrong internet address or he adds special chars to the address.
2. **Error full Cookies**: If the Cookie inside your browser is to old or broken it can also be a 400.
3. **Old outdated DNS-Entries**: In your DNS-Cache could lie files that point to wrong or outdated IP- addresses
4. **Too big files**: when you try to upload very large files, the server can deny the request.
5. **Too long header lines**: the communication between the client and server is done with header information about the request. some servers set a limit to the header length.

**Also if you can find out the more specific 400 error like this:**

```
400.1: Invalid Destination Header
400.2: Invalid  Depth Header
400.3: Invalid If Header
400.4: Invalid  Overwrite Header
400.5: Invalid  Translate Header
400.6: Invalid  Request Body
400.7: Invalid  Content
400.8: Invalid  Timeout
400.9: Invalid  Lock Token
```

If you are not the server admin you could ask him about specifications of the server. or use tools like postman where you can try to send requests to the server and find out more specific error codes.

Comment: I managed to get a reason for the 400. This is my response `400 invalid_content`. I'm not the server admin. I'm guessing this error tells me that my setup for the request is correct and I need to get the request content aligned with the server specs. Or am I wrong?

Comment: yes i would say like so. adjust your content.